# Passing information from dict to snakemake gives missing input file error

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I am reading in the input information using a csv file. Created a dict with needed/selected input parameters and passed to the shell script. I am getting missing inputfile error as follow:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 28 of /Users/ravinpoudel/Documents/neoantigen/devs/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule test_run:
HLA-A02:01
```

Following is my Snakefile.

```
samples = pd.read_csv("acc_filepath_df.csv").set_index("sample", drop=False)
sids=samples['sample']


def info_dict_from_sample(wildcards):
    return {
    "filepath": samples.loc[wildcards.sample, "filepath"], 
    "hla": samples.loc[wildcards.sample, "HLA"]
  }


expected_filenames = "mhctyped/{sample}.txt.gz"

rule all:
    input:
        expand(expected_filenames,
            zip,
            sample=sids)

rule test_run:
    input:
        unpack(info_dict_from_sample)
    output:
        "mhctyped/{sample}.txt.gz"
    shell:
        "cat {input.filepath} {input.hla} > {output}"
```

Comment: Are you sure your OS supports filenames with colons `:`, like `HLA-A02:01`?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info, but my first thought would be that `info_dict_from_sample` might be returning an empty dictionary.